# Update minimum value column of selected rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table is-

```
## meters ##
meter_num--------reading1---------reading2-------reading3-------reading4
 123               12               14             15               10        
 345               14               15             16               19
```

For each row I want to update the minimum valued column to a given value (say zero).
I know by using 'LEAST' function I can get the min value among the columns. But How do I update that minimum valued column from here?
e.g.
when I execute -

```
SELECT 
LEAST(reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4)
 FROM meters
 WHERE meter_num = '123'
```

returns -

```
reading4
  10
```

now I want to update reading4 to something else. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates and none of the values are `NULL`, you can use `case` expressions:

```
update meters
    set reading1 = (case when reading1 = least(reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4) then 0 else reading1 end),
        reading2 = (case when reading2 = least(reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4) then 0 else reading2 end),
        reading3 = (case when reading3 = least(reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4) then 0 else reading3 end),
        reading4 = (case when reading4 = least(reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4) then 0 else reading4 end);
```

Note:  This problem would be simpler if the readings were in separate *rows* rather than separate *columns*.

You can handle duplicates with a tweak:

```
update meters
    set reading1 = (case least(reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4)
                         when reading 1 then 0
                         else reading1
                   end),
        reading2 = (case least(reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4)
                         when reading1 then reading2
                         when reading2 then 0
                         else reading2
                    end),
        reading3 = (case least(reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4)
                         when reading1 then reading3
                         when reading2 then reading3
                         when reading3 then 0
                         else reading3
                    end),
       reading4 = (case least(reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4)
                         when reading1 then reading4
                         when reading2 then reading4
                         when reading3 then reading4
                         when reading4 then 0
                         else reading2
                    end),
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Only,  you should change the variables before 'end' in all lines and make it (reading1, reading2, reading3, reading4 resp) because it will cause to duplicate the values of reading1 to all columns.